# create soap request string with xmlbeans and axis2

Tags: soap, request, apache-axis, xmlbeans

i have a web service client which uses axis2 1.6.1, xmlbeans. It works fine.
Now, i want to create a string of soap request message (not only a xml string but also a soap string) from request object.

Please help.

(using jaxb or cxf are not options for this project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i worked it out. After you have xmlbean object, just do string concatenate between soap envelope and xmlObject.toXML().

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>

+ xmlObject.toXML()

+  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```